# upload artifacts to S3 using jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries

I have a requirement where I need to upload the artifacts generated after the build is success to S3 using shared libraries!

I am aware that there is a S3 plugin of Jenkins available that exposed a step with which we can upload to S3.

But I need to use library and not the exposed jenkins pipeline step!

What have I tried:

```
class S3Upload implements Serializable {
    private String _artifactsPath

    S3Upload(String artifactsPath) {
        _artifactsPath = artifactsPath
    }

    void build() {
        IStepExecutor steps = ContextRegistry.getContext().getStepExecutor()
        int returnStatus = steps.sh("echo \"building ${this._artifactsPath}...\"")
        if (returnStatus != 0) {
            steps.error("Some error")
        }
    }
}
```

I have written the above code for uploading to s3!

Can we use the existing s3 plugin in someway in shared library to upload to S3??

Comment: Why is your code referring to Artifactory and isn't referring to s3?

Comment: @MaratC I have edited the answer to use step.sh which I have defined under a groovy file. I need some information on what would be the best way to use s3upload from shared library! Can we use the `s3upload` plugin step from `s3 publisher` directly ?